# Animating using onmousedown when clicking on background

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

I have a small image in my HTML page. I need that to be animated when I click the BackGround of the page? I know that I have to achieve this by the `onmousefunction` but when I add that function to the `body` tag it does not work.

```
<script>
<body background = "src\img.jpg" onmousedown:moveRight();>

</body>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want "onclick=moveRight()" not "onmouseclick:moveRight()"

Answer (score 0):

Simply set an EventListener on the page, and add your function to it, no inline javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 html:
    <body background = "src\img.jpg" onclick=moveRight();>   
    </body>
/*************************************************************/
<body background = "src\img.jpg" onmousedown=moveRight();>   
    </body>
```

dont write html inside the script tag